# how to trigger a segue from the UITableView swipe to Edit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I am trying to include a swipe feature in my `UITableView` and I will like to perform a segue from there. For instance when cell is swiped to the left it reveals an `Edit` button and when this edit button is pressed it opens a new `ViewController.UI`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
let cSelector : Selector = “swipeAction”

let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: cSelector)
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
mainTableView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe) // Or you can add it to cell
```

And create swipe action :

```
func swipeAction()
{
    // TODO 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: nil)
}
```

Or you can call segue directly form when you swiped cell (If you implemented built in swipe like `canEditCellForRow`)

And implement `prepareForSegue` method

```
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as YourDestViewController
    controller.someData = // Pass some object if you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To preform a segue in code, you would use the line of code: `self.preformSegueWithIdentifyer("idenyidfyer",nil`. To make a segue in the view view controller, control click and drag from the view controller to a desired view controller. Click on the segue and change the identifier to what ever you want.

Comment: The line of code is similar to what I wrote, not exact.